# Trying to change the background color of cell generated from a loop of JSON data using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Well ive got this code that creates a table from JSON data. If a specific value is true, i would like that cells color to be set to red. I feel like what i have should work, but it doesnt....

I would really like to do this with jquery if possible and im sure it is. I was able to set the entire row using my function with the class name. I was also able to get the specific cell to change when clicked. But i just cant seem to get it to set it when the page loads

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>jQuery Test Stuff</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {



    var info = [{"Id":1,"Text":"Changed Location B","Summary":"PED","Complete":true},
    {"Id":2,"Text":"MA_HolyOke","Summary":"MAT","Complete":true},
    {"Id":3,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"PED","Complete":false},
    {"Id":4,"Text":"MA_South Shore","Summary":"ICU","Complete":true},
    {"Id":5,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"MAT","Complete":false},
    {"Id":6,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"MAT","Complete":false},
    {"Id":7,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"MAT","Complete":true},
    {"Id":8,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"ICU","Complete":true},
    {"Id":9,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"ICU","Complete":true},
    {"Id":10,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"MAT","Complete":false},
    {"Id":11,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"PED","Complete":true},
    {"Id":12,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"PED","Complete":false},
    {"Id":13,"Text":"MA_NEMC","Summary":"MAT","Complete":true},

    ];







    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
        {
            var hospId = info[i].Id;
            var subText = info[i].Summary;
            var hospital = info[i].Text;
            var complete = info[i].Complete;

            var fred = ('<td class="something"> ' + hospId +  ' </td>')



            if(subText == "PED")
            {

                $("#PED").append(fred);

            }

            if(subText == "MAT")
            {

                $("#MAT").append(fred);

            }

            if(subText == "ICU")
            {

                $("#ICU").append(fred);

            }

            if(complete == true)
            {
                //alert(fred);
                $(fred).css("background-color","red");

            }


        }









});
});

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <table id='beds' cellpadding="20">
  <tr id="PED"><td>PED</td></tr>
  <tr id="MAT"><td>MAT</td></tr>
  <tr id="ICU"><td>ICU</td></tr>
  </table>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot $ in front of your markup. Should be:

```
var fred = $('<td class="something"> ' + hospId +  ' </td>')
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rc33n/

Comment: Wow! I thought it would be a simple fix...but really? That simple? Every little character matters in code and it shows here haha. But thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

First off,  with jQuery 1.7, you dont need

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Simple change too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // do onload work here
    });
</script>
```

Guess you don't need it anymore, but i made a fiddle here that does what you're talking about in full jQuery, just heads up

Comment: Yea i wasnt sure about that and hadnt cared to check it out yet. But ive fixed it now and all is well still. Well except my original issue. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

fred is a string, you need to reference a selector like

```
$('.something').css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: Your code works but not as intended. It will set everything with that class name to red. But i was missing a $ when i defined my variable. But thank you